# Update database with php is not working

Tags: php, mysql, post

i have a form to update informations about a product. the form gets the values from the database and sends it to the page that should update the database. i checked that form sends the values to the second page correctly. but the update function of database is not updating.

the code of the update (second) page is like that:

```
include("database.php"); 

if (isset($_REQUEST["kullanici"])) {
include "database.php";
$sql = ("select * from uye");
}
else {
header ("Location: uyari.html");
}

$id = $_POST['id'];
$urunadi = $_POST['urunadi']; 
$malzemekodu = $_POST['malzemekodu']; 
$urunkategorisi = $_POST['urunkategorisi']; 
$birim = $_POST['birim']; 
$miktar = $_POST['miktar']; 
$personel = $_POST['personel']; 
$birimfiyat = $_POST['birimfiyat']; 
$fiyatbirimi = $_POST['fiyatbirimi']; 
$resim = $_POST['resim']; 

$sql = ("UPDATE depo SET id = $id, urunadi = $urunadi, malzemekodu = $malzemekodu, urunkategorisi = $urunkategorisi, birim = $birim, miktar = $miktar, personel = $personel, birimfiyat = $birimfiyat, fiyatbirimi = $fiyatbirimi, resim = $resim WHERE id = $id");
$kayit = mysql_query($sql);

if (isset ($kayit)){
echo "Stok Kaydınız Yapılmıştır.";

}
else {
echo "Stok Kayıt Başarısız.";
}
```

how could i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

query variable should be  quoted try change update query to

```
$sql = ("UPDATE depo SET id = '$id', urunadi = '$urunadi', malzemekodu = '$malzemekodu', urunkategorisi = '$urunkategorisi', birim = '$birim', miktar = '$miktar', personel = '$personel', birimfiyat = '$birimfiyat', fiyatbirimi = '$fiyatbirimi', resim = '$resim' WHERE id = '$id'");
```

If still issue check your post data is getting on this page Also use `mysql_real_escape_string()` to escape your post data

**Note** :- `mysql_*` has been deprecated use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: thank you for your answer; mysql worked with the quotes. i have a different page that does the same work with only amount increment (miktar). it changes only one variable and there is no quotes on that file like that; $sql = ("UPDATE depo SET miktar = $cikar WHERE id = $id"); -- which is working fine. so i couldn't think that the problem could be due to the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You must add quotes around the fields when updating / inserting strings. The same applies to date fields.

Also you should format all strings with `mysql_real_escape_string()` as this prevents hackers being able to attack your database by passing SQL in the string. For integers and floats you should use `intval()` and `floatval()` for the same reason.

Lastly, you should also length cut a string to the text length of the string field, in PHP use `substr()`. This prevents an error if the string length is longer than the field allows (some older browsers don't support lengthcut).

```
$personel = mysql_real_escape_string(substr($_POST['personel'], 0, 45)); // 45 = string length
$id = intval($_POST['id']);
```

Try using mysqli instead of mysql (depreciated) in PHP, you can also use PDO, however PDO is not as comprehensive and upto date as MYSQLI, and due to this is slightly slower.  The only advantage of PDO over MYSQLI is that PDO also works with PostgeSQL, so switching database engine is easier, however the SQL between MYSQL and PostreSQL differ slightly, so it's not that easy.